# Maven: not to build specified jar at build path

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jax-rs

I have added these dependency in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Seems it adding both jsr311-api (JAX-RS 1.x) and javax.ws.rs-api (JAX-RS 2.x). These two versions conflict my project deploying on JBoss As 7.1.1. So I want to tell maven not to build  jsr311-api (JAX-RS 1.x) jar file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Seems this is not working.

Comment: What is the build error that is displayed?

Comment: There is no buid error. completes fine

Comment: then how do you know it's not working? What does mvn dependency:tree tell you?

Comment: the jar (jsr311-api)  is still there. I want to stop building it

Comment: `javax.ws.rs-api` doesn't pull in `jsr311-api`. If `jsr311-api` is getting pulled in, then it is something else that is pulling it in. Use `mvn dependency:tree` to find out.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you check first your project dependency tree using below **mvn** command

> mvn enforcer:enforce

It will useful to find any dependency conflicts in your project 
then you can resolve any conflicts in project manually.